# Работа с toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал вот такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button1").on(function() {
var e1 = $(this).data("target1");
$(e1)toggleClass("rectangle1--open");
})
});
```

--
Всё верно подключил, но почему то не работает??
Подскажите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: `$(".button1").on(function()`  что `on` ?  там событие должно быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если вам нужен клик по элементу то `$(".button1").click(...)`. Внутри функции так же есть опечатки.

```js
$(function(){
   $(".button1").click(function() {
       var e1 = $(this).data("target1");
       $(e1).toggleClass("rectangle1--open");
    })
});
```

```css
#t {
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   
   border: 2px solid grey; 
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 50px;
}

#t.rectangle1--open {
   background-color: orange;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button1" data-target1="#t">тест</a>

<div id="t">toggle</div>
```